# Peer to Peer Replication Current Identity Not Similar

Tags: sql-server, transactional-replication

I am using peer to peer replication for 2 databases. I am replicating some tables with ID as primary key and identity(1,1). I noticed that in the subscriber database, the current identity of the table is not similar with the current identity of the table being published. The data being inserted is correct. If the insert will happen on the subscriber table, it will cause duplicate error. How do I sync both current identity?

Answer (score 0):

Using IDENTITY property don't you have to initialize as IDENTITY (1,2) in one environment and IDENTITY (2,2) in the other to handle inserts?

That's the inherent problem using autonumber in peer to peer...what if you have more than two environments? It gets tricky.